# db.Key.from_path() does not return correct key

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using db.Key.from_path(Model, key_name) in several different places in my code and then call either db.get() or Model.get_by_key_name(). I noticed that these latter commands were always returning 0 items even though I knew for sure I should be getting something back. Upon closer inspection, I noticed that the db.Key.from_path() command was not returning the correct key. The key returned looks very similar, especially at the beginning, but some of the characters are different and it is about 75% shorter than the key shown in the datastore viewer. Has anyone else encountered this? Thanks.

Here is some sample code:

```
class Root(db.Model):
    pass

class Parent(db.Model):
    pass

class MyModel(db.Model):
    pass

root = Root().put()
parent = Parent(key_name=parentname,parent=root).put()
mymodel = MyModel(key_name=mymodelname,parent=parent).put()

mymodel_k = db.Key.from_path('Parent','parentname','MyModel','mymodelname')
mymodel = db.get(mymodel_k)
```

mymodel is None

Comment: Key.from_path "builds a new Key object from an ancestor path of one or more entity keys", so is this what you are trying to do? Posting some relevant code will go a long way in getting a good answer.

Comment: @Sologoub: Key.from_path returns the same key(s) if you provide the same paramenters.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I have included some sample code.

Answer (score 2):

you are not constructing the path correctly with all the ancestors.

```
root = Root().put()  
parent = Parent(key_name=parentname, parent=root).put()  
mymodel = MyModel(key_name=mymodelname, parent=parent).put()
```

Root    -> has no parents
Parent  -> has parent Root
MyModel -> has parent Parent

`db.Key.from_path('Parent','parentname','MyModel','mymodelname')`
this one misses the Root ancestor which is contained in the Parent Key.

the right key would be:

```
db.Key.from_path('MyModel', 'mymodelname', parent=parent)
```

and this is why they key you create is shorter! one ancestor is missing.

Comment: Thank you, @aschmid00. So if I'm calling this in its own method, do I need to first run do a query to get parent in order to use it in db.Key.from_path()?

Comment: the problem in your case is that you dont know and cant construct the Root key because you let it autoassign by the system. that means that if you really need to Root entity you could give that one a key you define too so you would not need the query. if you leave it like that yes you will need to query the parent entity.

Comment: you are welcome. set the check on the right answer so the question is set as solved

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are two ancestor levels, so you should use this:

```
Key.from_path('Root', root.key().id(), 'Parent','parentname','MyModel','mymodelname')
```

or

```
Key.from_path('Parent','parentname','MyModel','mymodelname', parent=root)
```

Comment: Thank you, @Guido van Rossum!

Comment: isn't this the same answer from ascmid00?